# Convert docker-compose.yml to runc config.json

Tags: docker, docker-compose, runc, containerd

I want to convert docker-compose.yml to (a set of) runc config.json.

I found so far:

- copying config.json from running docker container ([is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303822/getting-runc-config-json-from-docker-container))
- somehow using [dockerd API](https://github.com/containerd/containerd#oci-runtime-specification) to create config.json from Docker Image

None of these handle parsing of the docker-compose.yml into usable runc specification. Does there exist something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a YAML parser to parse the docker-compose.yml. It turns out there are not that many things that a runc config has to get from the docker-compose.yml

1. read_only
2. command
3. working_dir
4. environment variables
5. tty
6. capabilities
7. memory limits
8. hostname
9. cgroup_parent
10. pid
11. ipc
12. volumes

most of which are not really relevant to most configurations